# Cannot call Thread's init() method for Jython class

Tags: java, multithreading, jython, init

Here is a sample of class that I am actually writing in Jython:

```
from threading import Thread

class MyClass(Thread)

    def __init__(self, mylist):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mylist = mylist
```

And I get the error:

```
File 'myfile.py', line 4, in __init__   at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)

java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly answer why this happens, I would almost always choose to create a `Runnable` and pass it to the `Thread(Runnable)` constructor in preference to subclassing `Thread` itself.

This might work around your problem.